# Difference between datagrid and gridview

Tags: asp.net-2.0

i want to know the main difference between datagrid and gridview in asp.net 2.0

Answer (score 2):

Check out the release from MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163933.aspx